# Remove query string pairs until a result is returned

Tags: html, query-string, search-form

Lets say I have a search form on my site which generates a query string to filter results, eg. `mysite/search?field1=value1&field2=value2&field3=value3`

The user enters the following into the search fields:

```
Field 1 = Cat
Field 2 = Black
Field 3 = Stray
```

Given the nature of a query string, all three field values would have to be present in an item being searched, in order for it to be recognised as a match.. right?

Is there a way to either make the '&' an 'OR', so that any matching field will return a result.

Or

Is there a way to match the nearest result? Ie. Remove string pairs until a match is found, or in some way, find the next closest result.

For example. If the user enters 'Cat', 'Black' and 'Stray' and there is an item that includes all three values, it returns that result (standard response). If there isn't an item that includes all three values, let's say there's only an item that has 'Cat' and 'Stray', it recognizes there are no items containing all three values, so it looks for two field value matches instead?

Happy to consider any ideas to prevent "no items found" and at least render something rather than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're using for filtering but general idea is that after you filter the data you check if it is empty and if it is you remove one filter do the filtering again. Something like this for example:

```
result = filter(data,filters);
while(!result || filters.length > 0){
  filters.pop();
  result = filter(data, filters);
}
```

Not working code, just general idea.

Comment: Thanks Gray, I'll have a play with something like that and see what I come up with.